# 206 Partial Content does not accept data from server

Tags: http, web, video, partial, http-status

I'm trying return video partially, using 206 Partial Content, I transfer all the headers correctly, but the request passes only 4kb, but if I answer 200 OK, the video will work, what could be the problem?

(If I answer 200 OK, then I can't rewind the video)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Type: Document

Request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.9
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 11 Mar 2019 19:03:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: video/mp4; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 11 Mar 2019 19:03:02 GMT
Content-Length: 16766763
Keep-Alive: timeout=15,max=100
```

=============================================

Type: Media

Request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.9
Range: bytes=0-
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 11 Mar 2019 19:03:02 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: video/mp4; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 11 Mar 2019 19:03:02 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15,max=100
Content-Range: bytes 0-29593599/29593600
Content-Length: 29593600
```

Comment: Strange, That all looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in localhost, everything works on server, thanks :)